# Is the story of 'Man of Steel' a fresh idea or is it inspired by any existing work?

Tags: man-of-steel, comic-adaptation, dc-extended-universe

The story of [Man of Steel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_of_Steel_%28film%29), the new Superman movie, is much different from existing live action and animated films and shows. Was it all made as a fresh idea or was it inspired by some existing Superman storyline, especially the new origin story?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a [Screen Rant article](http://screenrant.com/zack-snyder-superman-reboot-story-comics-rob-83061/) with the title "Zack Snyder’s ‘Superman’ Not Based on
Comics", Rob Keyes noted that director Zack Snyder has previously been known for making
quite literal adaptations of his source material.  But this film is different:

> With the Superman reboot however, Snyder will take a different route and will instead deliver a new origin story not based on any specific origin story or mini-series from the DC comics.

The same point is made more recently in a [review](http://www.examiner.com/review/movie-review-man-of-steel-boldly-reinvents-an-icon) from Examiner.com:

> Snyder, Nolan, and Goyer have each gone to great lengths to explain that their picture is an all-new approach and interpretation not based on any particular comic book story and not connected in any way to anything Donner or Reeve.

Answer (score 3):

They may have forged a new approach not based specifically on one book, but as the article [here](http://thisisinfamous.com/forging-man-of-steel-looking-at-the-works-that-influenced-the-superman-relaunch/) notes, some dialogue and scenes were adapted from "Superman: Earth One", John Byrne's Superman run, "Superman: Birthright" and "All-Star Superman".